# Customize Community Manager Menu

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder, napili

Is it possible to customize Customize Community Manager Menu ?

I need to add funcionality in order to let the community manager admin the site in only one place.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Salesforce Success
No. Those are the configuration options available to configure and admin the Community.